# Why does `hg diff -I filename` not show my file buried in a subdirectory?

Tags: linux, command-line, hg

Sometimes I make a few changes before remembering to commit.  Sometimes they are unrelated.  So I first `hg stat` to see which files I changed, and then I `hg diff` specific files if I don't remember every change I made to them, so I can make an accurate description in my commit message.

I have a file in my project, `a/b/c.pl`, which is listed when I `hg stat`.  However, if I `hg diff -I *c*` no results are shown, just the command prompt again.  AFAICT from `hg diff -h` I am using the correct syntax, but apparently not.  So, what's the correct syntax to see `c.pl`'s differences without having to type the whole path?

Comment: Normally one has to type the full path, unless something like `*/*/c.pl` worked. You'd still need one star per directory though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is `hg diff -I **c*`.